# GNU Octave fail hex2dec

Tags: octave

Encounter fail with some HEX to DEC [conversions](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/String-Conversions.html)

```
b = '0x170d21b9' 
bdec = hex2dec(b)
```

Return the

```
bdec = NaN
```

But should be 386736569

How to convert the hexadecimal number to integer in above example?

Comment: Alternatively, leave off the single quotes and Octave will read the hex value correctly: `b = 0x170d21b9` results in `b = 386736569`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave off the 0x. This is a notation used in some languages to denote that the number is hex, but isn't actually part of the number. Octave's hex2dec function doesn't use that. Put `b = '170d21b9'` and you will get `bdec =  386736569`.